# Styling multiple features in shapefile using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, sld

I have a shapefile loaded in a GeoServer instance, and I need some guidance on how to best style the output. The file is depicting public/private land ownership in the State of Colorado. The shapefile has different feature properties (adm_name) for each agency - State Land, BLM, US Forest Service, Private, etc. Each type of ownership needs to be a different color.

A PNG image of the unstyled map is here.

[image]

I need it to look like this (without the grid, of course).

[image]

So, this is as much a theoretical question as a technical one.

Can I just apply the styling with a SLD file? Or inline in the web browser through the Leaflet code? Or should the features be split up into different layers and a single style applied to each layer? Or something else completely?

It's currently a huge resource to load on a web page. So, any suggestions to accomplish this efficiently are most welcome.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html, especially http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html#attribute-based-polygon

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a "large" file your best bet is to style it on the server and use the WMS service to send it to your browser as a small image (i.e. a compressed png).

GeoServer uses SLD to style layers, there are many examples available in the [SLD cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html) which you can use as a basis for your style. In your case I would recommend using the [`recode` function](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-tipstricks/transformation-func.html#recode) as being the easiest and probably quickest.

Comment: OK, I think I'm following you, and I had seen the recode function in the SLD Cookbook. My question now is in response to your answer. You said, "send it to your browser as a small image (i.e. a compressed png). "That's where I'm scratching my head. I don't want a single image. I want it is a zoomable/togglable tile layer on an interactive map.

Comment: That is how GeoServer works.